# Values returned by E820h QuerySystemAddressMap on 4GB+ memory

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-64, bios

I just finished writing a [review for a program that displays the results from QuerySystemAddressMap](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167158/e820-display-using-x86-legacy-boot-sector-or-dos-6-22-com-file/169385#169385).
I'm left with 2 questions:

1. Seeing those - for the most needlessly large - 32-bit parameters `ECX`, `EBX`, and especially the function number in `EAX`, I suspect there could exist a protected mode counterpart for this BIOS function. Is my suspicion correct?
2. When [the BIOS function 0000E820h](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/mem64mb.html) runs **from real address mode** on a computer with more than 4GB memory and knowing that memory above the 4GB mark will not be addressable, will the addresses and lengths that are reported stay below 4GB?

Normally I would just give this a try and find out on my own, but I don't have this kind of hardware (yet).

Comment: You don't have hardware with more than 4 GB of memory? Because every system, even the brand new ones, boot up in real mode, so that would be easy to test. As far as I know, *none* of the ROM BIOS interrupts are accessible from protected mode. [This reference](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/mem64mb.html) suggests E820h is real-mode only, too. I think it's just historical why it uses 32-bit registers: it was introduced for the Compaq SystemPro, which was the first system to have need for it, and this used a 386 processor. Why *not* use the full registers?

Comment: @CodyGray I somewhat presumed there could have been something similar to the *ProtectedModeEntryPoint* available on the VESA video BIOS. And as to "why *not* use the full registers", all of those operand size prefixes and 32-bit immediates take up a lot of bytes in real address mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BIOS function INT 15h EAX=0000E820h is designed to get a complete memory map of the system and is designed to overcome the limitation on previous interfaces of not supporting memory above 4 GB. As such it would make no sense for this function to not report memory above 4 GB. There's no protected mode equivalent BIOS function. (Although the UEFI GetMemoryMap service provides equivalent functionality when booting through UEFI rather than the legacy BIOS boot method.)

The function is meant to be called in real mode before an operating system enters protected mode. The few additional code bytes that using 32-bit registers requires in real mode is insignificant. Most operating systems will reclaim the memory used by the early real mode boot code anyways.

Comment: It's unfortunate that what is essentially`GetMemoryMap` in legacy systems or at least those using BIOS to boot, has to be so convoluted.  AMI rev 6.05 01/18/11 core 08.00.16 copies the int 15H handler to 99FB:0 and the 20-byte members live @ 99FB:90H. Be a lot more convenient if AX=E820 would just return a pointer to that array.